# How to store the operations performed by a user in Elastic Search?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I am making a react application where there will be few buttons like sorting, removing duplicates etc. And there will be input field to get the text(for example, the text that has to be sorted) and there will also be output field to display the result. I also have login and sign up page in this application, so that only registered users can use the application. Now I want to have a history view for all the operations performed by each user. To store the history, I will be using Elastic Search. I'm absolutely new to ElasticSearch. So I would like to get some rough idea or a blueprint like what are the steps I will have to follow. Much appreciated.

I've used Java in the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is highlevel idea you can implement for user tracking:

1. Log each action of user into log files.
2. Use Logstash [File Input Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) or Filebeat [Log Input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html) for reading your file and indexing to the elasticsearch using [output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).
3. Use Kibana for [visulization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html).

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate on Point no 1

Comment: As you are using Java at server side, use log4j to write log to logs files. let consider user is clicking on login button so that request will come to your application with userid who is trying to login so you can log this even to log file and similar way for other action.

Comment: That was really helpful. Is it possible to write multiple attributes like userid as well as the commands in a single log into the log file. Is that possible?

Comment: @Shelton you can write anything in logs file. You can create json format log with multipul key-value and then index that to elasticsearch. Also, if you have plain text log files then you can use Grok pattern to convert it to strcture format.